# gdb log file format

Tags: gdb, cgdb

When I use `set logging on` in gdb, the output to the log file has a different format than what I see on the terminal screen. The logfile is not very readable. How can I get the log file in a readable format?

**Output to screen is fine:**

```
(gdb) p foo
$1 = {
  static npos = 18446744073709551615,
  _M_dataplus = {
    <std::allocator<char>> = {
      <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
    members of std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider:
    _M_p = 0x601028 "Hello World!\n"
  }
}
```

**Output to log file is not very readable:**

```
^Z^Zpost-prompt

^Z^Zbreakpoints-headers

^Z^Zfield 0
Num     
^Z^Zfield 1
Type           
^Z^Zfield 2
Disp 
^Z^Zfield 3
Enb 
^Z^Zfield 4
Address            
^Z^Zfield 5
What

^Z^Zbreakpoints-table

^Z^Zrecord

^Z^Zfield 0
1       
^Z^Zfield 1
breakpoint     
^Z^Zfield 2
keep 
^Z^Zfield 3
y   
^Z^Zfield 4
0x0000000000400961 
^Z^Zfield 5
in main at test.cpp:9
        breakpoint already hit 1 time

^Z^Zbreakpoints-table-end

^Z^Zpost-prompt

^Z^Zvalue-history-begin 1 -
$1 = 
^Z^Zvalue-history-value
{

^Z^Zfield-begin -
static npos
^Z^Zfield-name-end
 = 
^Z^Zfield-value
18446744073709551615
^Z^Zfield-end
, 

^Z^Zfield-begin -
_M_dataplus
^Z^Zfield-name-end
 = 
^Z^Zfield-value
{
    <std::allocator<char>> = {
      <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
    members of std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::_Alloc_hider: 

^Z^Zfield-begin *
_M_p
^Z^Zfield-name-end
 = 
^Z^Zfield-value
0x601028 "Hello World!\n"
^Z^Zfield-end

  }
^Z^Zfield-end

}

^Z^Zvalue-history-end

^Z^Zpost-prompt

^Z^Zbreakpoints-headers

^Z^Zfield 0
Num     
^Z^Zfield 1
Type           
^Z^Zfield 2
Disp 
^Z^Zfield 3
Enb 
^Z^Zfield 4
Address            
^Z^Zfield 5
What

^Z^Zbreakpoints-table

^Z^Zrecord

^Z^Zfield 0
1       
^Z^Zfield 1
breakpoint     
^Z^Zfield 2
keep 
^Z^Zfield 3
y   
^Z^Zfield 4
0x0000000000400961 
^Z^Zfield 5
in main at test.cpp:9
        breakpoint already hit 1 time

^Z^Zbreakpoints-table-end

^Z^Zpost-prompt
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must be using this from some kind of IDE, which turns on `MI` (machine interface). The output you see is made for easy parsing by another program, but not for human consumption.

It is likely a bug that MI interface also affects the format of `gdb.txt` log. Please file a bug about it [here](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi).

As a workaround, run GDB outside of the IDE to collect easy to read `gdb.txt`.

Comment: You are right, I was using cgdb. When using gdb, the log file is fine. Can't believe I didn't try that before posting! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @matthiash good you did post. I was in the same situation